# How do I make the flexbox items fit their image size?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The problem is, the images as a whole have to stretch to fit the window as it resizes.

Most of the images work fine but the last one has a different width and it just resizes to a huge size.

It has to be position absolute because there is a web canvas underneath.

I think I tried everything, all the flex-grow, flex-basis stuff. I don't get it.

As you can see in the example, the last image should fit heightwise with the others but I cant get it to fit.

http://jsfiddle.net/huvogt3g/

```css
.container img {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 40%;
  background: #777;
}

.container2 {
  width: 12.5%;
  background: #777;
}

.myflex {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="myflex">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/512x512/000088/ffffff" />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/512x512/000088/ffffff" />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/512x512/000088/ffffff" />
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <img style="" src="https://placehold.it/64x512/000088/ffffff" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this flexbox in one line

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> body{margin:0;}
.flex-container { 

  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row;
  flex-flow: row;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-item:nth-of-type(1) { flex-grow: 1; }
.flex-item:nth-of-type(2) { flex-grow: 1; }
.flex-item:nth-of-type(3) { flex-grow: 2; }
.flex-item4:nth-of-type(4) { flex-grow: 1; }
.flex-item {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 40%; 
}
.flex-item 4{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 10%; 
    margin: 10px;
}
.flex-item img{
    width: 100%;    height: 100%;
}.flex-item4 img{
    width: 100%;    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"> <img src="https://placehold.it/512x512/000088/ffffff" /></div>
  <div class="flex-item"> <img src="https://placehold.it/512x512/000088/ffffff" /></div>
  <div class="flex-item"> <img src="https://placehold.it/512x512/000088/ffffff" /></div>  
  <div class="flex-item4">  <img style="" src="https://placehold.it/64x512/000088/ffffff" /></div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you explain the `.flex-item 4 {}` syntax? It is invalid in vscode but it works. I tried saying `flex-item4 {}` instead but it doesnt work anymore then. It also only works in Chrome based browsers, does not show the same correct result in Firefox or Edge.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give all time images the same height, simply add `display: flex;` to your `.container` and `.container2` classes.

Here's a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/huvogt3g/1/